# Assigning the value to the list from an array

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

res is list has 1867 value divided into 11 sets with different sets of elements.
`ex: res[0][:]=147,res[1][:]=174,res[2][:]=168` so on `total 11 set = 1867 elements`.

`altitude=[125,85,69,754,855,324,...]` has `1867 values`.
I need to replace the res list values with a continuous altitude values in a list.

I have tried:

```
for h in range(len(res)):
    res[h][:]=altitude
```

It is storing all 1867 values in all the sets. **I need the first 147 elements in set1, next (starting from 148th value) 174 elements in set2 so on...**

Thank You

Comment: `alist[n][:]` doesn't make much sense.  For a list the `[:]` just makes a shallow copy.  Is `res` a list that contains lists?  That "dividing into sets" bit isn't very  clear.  Make smaller concrete example.  With desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep track of the number of elements assigned at each iteration to get the correct slice from `altitude`. If I understand correctly `res` is a list of lists with varying length.
Here is a possible solution:

```
current_position = 0
for sublist in res:
    sub_len = len(sublist)
    sublist[:] = altitude[current_position: current_position + sub_len]
    current_position += sub_len
```